# Непонятный код на странице php

Tags: php, http

При загрузки страницы через ajax , появляются неожиданные символы в начале и конце текста. Если загружать страницу без использования ajax то все норм. Может кто знает как их отловить, явного вывода нигде нет.

http://c2n.me/3kkPkuS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**

```
if ($.support.pjax) {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-pjax]', function(event) {
      $.pjax.click(event, {container: $('#data-pjax-container')});
    });
}
```

Как-то у меня такое было, и там проблема вроде в сессии была... На локальной машине нормально работает, а вот на удаленной выводит такое.

Comment: визуально похоже на выдачу диагностики при сжатии трафика. но на страницу такое может попасть, наверно, только по ошибке. / сравните заголовки, которые выдаёт сервер в обоих случаях.

Comment: А можно сам JS скрипт?

Comment: Я думаю, он тут не причем.  Вообще pjax использую. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, это не сжатие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это число - это количество передаваемых данных - размер chunk'а. Там ещё в конце (после текста) 0 должен быть.

Как получилось, что скрипт не смог это обработать, я не знаю, возможно, ты пропустил оба заголовка `Content-Length` и `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, после чего стал отправлять данные как chunked.

[Википедия :: Chunked transfer encoding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Answer (score 1):

Решилось добавлением заголовка Content-Length. Без него символы выводятся, с ним все норм. Почему не понял (